# Nodejs Reactjs application error on await fetch "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

I am getting error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" Please see image also. How to resolve this please?

Error Image:
[image]

My code is below.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const InputTodo = () => {
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

    const onSubmitForm = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const body = { description };
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/todos", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            });

            window.location("/");
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h1 className="text-center mt-5">Pern Todo List</h1>
            <form className="d-flex mt-5" onSubmit={ onSubmitForm }>
                <input type="text" 
                className="form-control" 
                value={description}
                onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)}></input>
                <button className="btn btn-success">Add</button>
            </form>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default InputTodo;
```

Comment: Can you show your server configuration code?

Answer (score -1):

One of the simplest reasons to have such issue is to forget to start the backend app like in my case I tried to login my reactjs forgetting to run my backend app, so make sure every time to start all the apps.

Comment: After restarting the server, make sure that the server is running and serving requests. Check the console output or log files to see if there are any errors.